# How to convert json into String array

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Hi I'm very new to Swift and I'm trying to make a simple application.

The app gets data from server as JSON format.

```
func addLangList(completion: @escaping ([String], [String]) -> Void) {

    let request = NetworkRequest()
    let reqUrl = NetworkInformation.serverAddr + "/word/purpose"
    let parameters: Parameters = ["category": "lang"]
    request.sendGetRequest(url: reqUrl, parameters: parameters, success: { (response) in

        let json = JSON(response)
        let isSuccess = json[ServerResponseKey.KEY_RESULT]


        if isSuccess == true {

            var resultMessage:JSON = json[ServerResponseKey.KEY_MESSAGE]

            let lang = resultMessage["lang"].arrayValue
            let purpose = resultMessage["purpose"].arrayValue


            completion(lang, purpose)
        }

    }, fail: request.CommonNetworkFailureHandler)
}
```

By using Swiftyjson, the function converts the data received into JSON format. Inside the closure, 'completion' is called for further process in caller. An error occurs at 'completion(lang, purpose). Xcode says

> " Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]' to expected argument type '[String]'".

The error,  I  guess, because `.arrayValue` doesn't change `resultMessage["lang"]` into `[String]` type....Can anyone give me some advice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 arrays

```
let lang = resultMessage["lang"].array
let purpose = resultMessage["purpose"].array
```

are of type `JSON` which isn't `String` , you need to cast them

```
let langStr = lang.map { $0.string }
let purposeStr = purpose.map { $0.string }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let langStr = lang.map { $0.string }
let purposeStr = purpose.map { $0.string }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: ok.. in this answer, we are mapping the string (as per requirement) value in the json as an assignment to the variable. Please see link below:
https://codeburst.io/swift-map-flatmap-filter-and-reduce-53959ebeb6aa

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Commentary to clarify the answer, belongs in the answer, not a comment.  Additionally, you've only retyped the contents of an answer posted prior to this post.